# .gitignore on a new repo (can't reset on a fresh repo)

Tags: git

This happens almost every time I init a new repo.

1. Start a new project.  Create a bunch of new files.
2. `git init`
3. `git add .`
4. Oh shoot, there's some IDE/build cruft I need to ignore.
5. `echo ".scons-nodecount" > .gitignore`
6. Dammit, .gitignore doesn't see it because this file has already been added.
7. `git reset .scons-nodecount`
8. Dammit, git reset doesn't work because there's no commits yet.

   ... not sure what to do here, so ...
9. Start over: `rm -rf .git`

-- edit --

How do I remove a file from the index on a fresh repo?  `git reset` is what I'd traditionally do, but it seems like this isn't allowed if there are no prior commits.

Comment: Your question is quite ambiguous, I suggest you edit it. Is your question: How do I retroactively add entries to my .gitignore file and have them apply to things previously added on a fresh repo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do the same thing all the time.  Try `git rm --cached .scons-nodecount`.  This will instruct Git to remove the file, but only from the index (`--cached`).

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to simply reset the full index, in case you don’t want to remove the files all manually using `git rm --cached` would be to just delete `.git/index`. This will reset everything without actually touching the files, so you don’t need to start over completely.

But of course `git rm --cached <file>` is what you’d usually do.

Comment: +1 This is definitely a better approach when it's more than just a handful of files you accidentally added and you just want to start over from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to configure a global template and write an IDE patterns to $GIT_DIR/info/exclude, so on each init you will have an exclude patterns for IDE or just use common file for all projects and specify `core.excludesfile` for it.

Comment: Actually I prefer to have those things in the `.gitignore` that is also included in the repository so *others* working on the project don’t commit those files either.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but for that case I put git template into the repository, so others can make `git init ./.git-template` to install templates for project. This includes special hooks, common settings, exclude patterns and aliases. This solution allows us to maintain git settings for application and we sure that each person has the same config (line-endings, etc..)